# How to get the postmeta field values in the posts wpgraphql query?

Tags: wordpress, wp-graphql

I am using wpgraphql to communicate with wordpress database. I have got one posts table in which I can see all the attributes of the post filled. There is a field for custom field too, I can see the value filled for custom field in the postMeta table ,but cannot get the meta field attribute in the subfield of the posts in the graphql query.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta still needs to be registered to the GraphQL schema before you can retrieve it from your request. Here's an example. Just replace `PostTypeName`, `field_name`, and `FieldType` with the what you need, put it in a theme's `functions.php` or a plugin to be run after `plugins_loaded` hook and before `graphql_register_types` hook and it should work.

```
add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
    register_graphql_field( 'PostTypeName', 'field_name', [
        'type' => 'FieldType',
        'resolve' => function( $post ) {
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post->databaseId, 'meta_key'  );
            return ! empty( $meta ) ? $meta : null;
        }
    ]);
});
```

The WPGraphQL docs has more info on this [here](https://www.wpgraphql.com/recipes/recipe-tags/custom-fields/)